# show data in UITableView on tapping UITextField

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uitextfield

How to get data in `UITableview` instead of tapping on keyboard `UITextfield`. In `UITableview`, how to do multiple selection of data.
Edited:- I have a `UITextfield`. On tapping it, tableview should pop up with data in it instead of keyboard. When a row of tableview is selected, then checkmark should appear and that data should be seen in `UITextfield`.

Comment: what exactly you want? Please write question in proper way.

Comment: load tableview in textViewDidBeginEditing.

Comment: Share your code. What have you tried?

Comment: Your requirement is when user touches textfield then keyboard should not show instead we need to show table view  and on selecting tableview cell that data should be displayed on text field?

Answer (score 4):

Answer of your first question -

Your keyboard will hide by using this code.

```
-(BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text {

    if([text isEqualToString:@"\n"]) {
       [textField resignFirstResponder];
       return NO;
    }
return YES;
}

- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField{

     [self.view endEditing:YES];
     // load your tableView here.
     // Everything must be custom.that is your table view is just like a popup.
}
```

Answer of your second question -

Now current scenario is your table view is shown on screen.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *selectedValue = [yourArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    yourTextView.text = selectedValue;
    yourTableView.hide = YES;
}
```

Here after selecting any row that value is shown in yourTextView.but after that you have to hide that tableView. Try this.May this will help you.

Answer (score 2):

```
-(void)textViewDidBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView  
{

 [self.view endEditing:YES]; // this will make key board hide   
 yourTableView.hide = NO;  // here show tableview make sure tableview allocated out side and here you will be just showing.  
}


-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath     
{  
yourTextView.text = yourArray[indexPath.row];  
yourTableView.hide = YES;  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use UITextField.inputView property.

More on the subject here:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/InputViews/InputViews.html